# How to display an image in an image button with shared preferences?

Tags: android, image, sharedpreferences

In one of my activities you can click on an image button and a dialog opens up to ask you to open up the Gallery. Once opened up you can click on one of those images in your gallery.

What I want that the clicked image is set as the image of the image button. This image should stay there even when the user kills the app (when he opens up the app again the chosen image should still be there).

I chose to do all this work with the shared preferences but can't get it working. I get an error when I click on an image in the gallery. Any suggestions??

UPDATE: The error I receive is:
Unfortunately, the process com.myname.android has stopped

Here is my code, beginning with the onActivityResult:

```
private String selectedImagePath;
private String mFileName;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

            Log.v("IMAGE PATH====>>>> ",selectedImagePath);
        }
        storePath();
        retrievePath();
        convertPathToImage();
    }
}

private void storePath() {
    final SharedPreferences sPreference = getSharedPreferences(
            "pref_key", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Editor spEditor = sPreference.edit();
    spEditor.putString("img_path", mFileName);
    spEditor.commit();
}

private void retrievePath() {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(
            "pref_key", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPreference.contains("img_path")) {
        mFileName = sharedPreference.getString("img_path",
                null);
    }
}

private void convertPathToImage() {
    File imgFile = new  File(mFileName);
    if(imgFile.exists()){

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

        ImageButton myImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image);
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

    }
}
```

And here is the LogCat:

```
05-30 15:27:14.567: D/dalvikvm(634): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 3% free 11478K/11783K, paused 5ms+4ms
05-30 15:27:14.597: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:14.617: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:14.926: D/gralloc_goldfish(634): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-30 15:27:26.767: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:26.877: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:30.616: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:30.626: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:32.086: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(634): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634): Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@4155da80 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@4155da80 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:763)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:567)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1043)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1030)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1024)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:341)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at com.android.internal.content.PackageMonitor.register(PackageMonitor.java:65)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onCreate(ResolverActivity.java:99)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity.onCreate(ChooserActivity.java:53)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-30 15:27:33.366: E/ActivityThread(634):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 15:27:35.987: V/IMAGE PATH====>>>>(634): /mnt/sdcard/Mercedes_SLS_AMG.jpg
05-30 15:27:36.176: D/AndroidRuntime(634): Shutting down VM
05-30 15:27:36.176: W/dalvikvm(634): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/20 }} to activity {com.xyz.android.taskreminder/com.xyz.android.taskreminder.ReminderEditActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2980)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3023)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1177)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at com.xyz.android.taskreminder.ReminderEditActivity.convertPathToImage(ReminderEditActivity.java:249)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at com.xyz.android.taskreminder.ReminderEditActivity.onActivityResult(ReminderEditActivity.java:227)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634):  ... 11 more
05-30 15:27:36.376: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:36.396: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:36.787: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:36.847: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:37.386: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:37.406: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:37.887: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:37.947: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:38.396: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:38.416: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:38.897: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:38.927: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:39.406: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:39.426: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:39.917: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:39.927: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:40.426: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:40.446: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:40.917: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:40.947: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:41.426: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:41.447: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:41.937: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:41.977: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:42.446: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:42.467: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:42.937: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:42.956: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:43.446: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:43.467: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:43.947: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:43.976: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:44.456: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:44.477: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:44.966: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:44.986: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-30 15:27:45.466: I/dalvikvm(634): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-30 15:27:45.487: I/dalvikvm(634): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: what error you have come? plz post log

Comment: See the error above in the update

Comment: You didn't post the error. Post the log from LogCat. Also, storing something in SharedPreferences just to retrieve it in the next line of code is really unefficient.

Comment: What error means can you post your logcat?

Comment: Ok, i have posted the log cat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@4155da80 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

This is probably a bug in Android. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29399. It shouldn't effect the app though which should still be able to get a result back from the gallery.

```
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/20 }} to activity {com.ndroidstudios.android.taskreminder/com.ndroidstudios.android.taskreminder.ReminderEditActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
...
05-30 15:27:36.206: E/AndroidRuntime(634): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is the problem. mFileName is null when you try to use it to create a new File. In retrievePath, when you try to pull "img_path" out of your preferences the default value is null, so I'm guessing it's getting set to null there. Check in the debugger to make sure mFileName is getting set to a valid String from your preferences.