# Proper way to get context of parent activity inside fragment fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I am developing small android application and in my application I am using fragment concept. In my one activity I am using multiple fragments and doing transitions of those fragment.
Now Inside one fragment I am displaying one alert dialog and for i need to pass context of activity. I did this in this following manner.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getSherlockActivity())
        .setTitle("Logout")
        .setMessage("Really Logout from App?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {


                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
```

Everything is working fine without any error and without any failure. Only one problem is that in logcat it showing me that my main activity has leaked intent.
Here is the problem; is this problem because I am passing `getsherlockActivity();` or because of some thing else?
Wanted to clarify this concept ...

Comment: Excuse me, but do you sure this message is related to this part of code, because i really don't know how `Activity` `Fragment` and `Dialog` can refer to `Intent`? Could you post original message about this leaked intent?

Comment: Hi Evos thank you for reply. I think you right.. Here is my full log cat regarding this problem `Activity XYZ has leaked IntentReceiver XYZ that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
` and i thing its related broadcast receiver ... right?                                     Thank you for your kind help...

Comment: Hi @nilkash, yep you're right, it's seems you forgot to unregistered one of your receivers. I will move my comment to an answer so you could upvote and/or check it as a correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me, but do you sure this message is related to this part of code, because i really don't know how `Activity` `Fragment` and `Dialog` can refer to `Intent`?

It looks like info level message related to BroadcastReceiver, not to this part of code. Here is couple of lins related to this problem: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299312/leaked-intentreceiver-in-google-cloud-messaging) and [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815416/how-to-display-an-image-in-an-image-button-with-shared-preferences)